# Knex Error: Transaction query already complete, run with DEBUG=knex:tx for more info

Tags: node.js, node-modules, knex.js

Here is how I am making the connection

```
  const config = {
  "client": "oracledb",
  "connection": {
    "host": configurations.host,
    "user": configurations.auth.username,
    "password": configurations.auth.password,
    "database": configurations.database
  },
  "useNullAsDefault": true,
  'debug': true
};
const db = await knex(config).transaction();
return { db, Models: Models(db) };
```

After the first queries are run and db.commit()/db.rollback() is called, I get the following error when I try to run more queries.

```
{
   method: 'first',
   options: {},
   timeout: false,
   cancelOnTimeout: false,
   bindings: [ 'D000314-1', '2', 1 ],
   __knexQueryUid: '6BeVaYF9P_Zq9kq8pJJoZ',
   sql: 'select * from (select * from "ADMIN"."AGILE2PIMWEB_PACKAGES" where "ITEM_NUMBER" = ? and "NEW_REV" = ? order by "CREATED_ON" desc) where rownum <= ?'
 }
 Error: Transaction query already complete, run with DEBUG=knex:tx for more info
     at completedError (/GS-Integrator/pimweb-adapter/node_modules/knex/lib/execution/transaction.js:396:9)
     at /GS-Integrator/pimweb-adapter/node_modules/knex/lib/execution/transaction.js:362:24
     at new Promise (<anonymous>)
     at Client_Oracledb.trxClient.query (/GS-Integrator/pimweb-adapter/node_modules/knex/lib/execution/transaction.js:358:12)
     at Runner.query (/GS-Integrator/pimweb-adapter/node_modules/knex/lib/execution/runner.js:130:36)
     at ensureConnectionCallback (/GS-Integrator/pimweb-adapter/node_modules/knex/lib/execution/internal/ensure-connection-callback.js:13:17)
     at Runner.ensureConnection (/GS-Integrator/pimweb-adapter/node_modules/knex/lib/execution/runner.js:272:20)
     at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
     at async Runner.run (/GS-Integrator/pimweb-adapter/node_modules/knex/lib/execution/runner.js:30:19)
```

There is a loop, and I am trying to commit changes with each iteration of the loop, but a single transaction is not allowing me this. Also, if I make a new knex connection for each iteration previous ones don't get destroyed and the pool becomes full eventually. Anybody who have faced a similar problem and knows a work around this?

Answer (score 0):

You should start the transaction before the loop (just one transaction) and then commit the transaction once the loop ends.